# Page Add SourceForge Projects is not translated to german

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

The page **Add SourceForge Projects** on [Careers Germany](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is not translated to german.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been translated.

[image: Add SourceForge in German]